# jQuery select next div

Tags: jquery

so code looks like this:
How can I change div1 when hovering over current link1 ?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class='link1'></a>
        <a class='link2'>
            <div class='div1'></div>
            <div class='div2'></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class='link1'></a>
        <a class='link2'>
            <div class='div1'></div>
            <div class='div2'></div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried like this:

```
$(".link1").hover(
function () {
        $(this).nextAll('.div1').css('display','block');
        ...
    },

    function () {
        ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.next` and `.nextAll` only search the "direct siblings".  The element you want is a child of the link's sibling.

You can try this:

```
$(this).next('.link2').children('.div1')
```

Or, you can travese to the parent and search *all* decendants:

```
$(this).parent().find('.div1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(".link1").hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().find(".div1").css('display','block');
}, function(){
   //
})
```

Comment: That's not what `.closest` does.  `.closest` traverses an element's parents until it matches the selector.